# GStreamer cascade of missing headers (starts with glib.h)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, include, header-files

I'm new to linux and I'm trying to compile some cpp code I've written in windows. I'm using Linux Mint 17.2 and Qt with qmake. I'm compiling a 32bit app on a 64bit system (don't know if it is relevant).The application uses gstreamer 0.10.

When I add the gst.h header to the app's includepath I start a cascade of missing headers starting with glib.h. After a while of tracking all missing headers and folders (libxml, asm-generic, asm and a lot of others) I finally end up not being able to find one.

My question is: Is this normal to be looking for all this headers? Shouldn't they be in some system includepath already to make it easier for installed software to find them?

Thank you in advance for any time you take to awnser me.

**UPDATE:**

When  use the 64-bit version of QtCreator the header files are found automatically. I wanted to compile a 32-bit version of the app but for now this will do I guess

Comment: You are probably missing some `dev` packages. Compiler only provides standard header files. You may have the library packages installed (runtime) but missing the `-dev` packages. `apt-get install libmissing-dev` will solve the issue, but you need to map the missing headers to the actual package providing them.

Comment: I have the libgstreamer0.10-dev installed. I'm not getting errors linking libraries. I just need to be adding a lot of folders to the includepath, some of them system source folders because the gestreamer gst.h needs them and can't find them. I'm wondering if that is normal...

Comment: `dev`packages usually place headers in system standard locations, e.g. `/usr/include`, that should be enough.

Comment: I think the problem mught be because I'm using the QtCreator 32-bit version

Comment: You don't need to use the 32bit version of QtCreator or the compiler to compile a 32bit executable. You need to use a proper cross-compiler.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.